# Emacs change file extension - mode association

Tags: emacs, octave

My Emacs opens .m files in ObjC mode. However I want to open them in Octave mode. I have already added to the `.emacs` file:

```
(autoload 'octave-mode "octave-mod" nil t)
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.m$" . octave-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

What else should I do? I do have Octave mode installed.

Comment: `"octave-mod"` is misspelled in your example.  Also, use `add-to-list` instead of `setq`/`cons`.  For more help, we'll need to know how you installed `octave-mode`.  More specifically, is `octave-mode.el` present in your `load-path`?

Comment: @lunaryorn I'm a newbie to Emacs. I use Emacs 24.2.1 on Windows 7. In `Options/Manage Emacs Packages` it says package `octave-mod` is built in. There is a file called `octave-mod.el` in the `emacs\lisp\progmodes`. What is the load path? (That directory should be pretty much in it :) )

Comment: Confirmed; the `octave-mode` in Emacs lives in the `octave-mod` library. Weird. You shouldn't need a custom autoload declaration for a built-in library, though; `octave-mode` should be autoloaded by default (or if it wasn't at the time, it certainly is now).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fortunately everything is working now and unfortunately I don't remember how I fixed it :) Maybe there was an error in my `.emacs` earlier. This is the more correct code:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.m$" . octave-mode))
```

Autoloading is unneeded in recent versions; if you do need to enable it, note that `"octave-mode"` is not a typo.

```
(autoload 'octave-mode "octave-mod" nil t)
```

Comment: if this does not work, try killing all the buffers where you have opened .m files and try to open a new .m file different from the ones you opened previously.

Comment: Is "octave-mod" a typo, though?

Comment: @Jed 9 years ago it worked this way. As to now, I have no idea.

Answer (score 4):

Use this.

```
;; octave-mode
(autoload 'octave-mode "octave-mode" "Loding octave-mode" t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.m\\'" . octave-mode))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this exact problem.
Your statement is correct, but your .emacs file probably isn't loading up correctly.  Emacs searches the "HOME" variable to load up preferences, lisp code etc.

To see what your HOME variable is:

Open scratch buffer (this is a "play place" to try things out):

```
C-x C-b *scratch* <RET>
```

Evaluate this expression by typing it, then putting the cursor to the right, then hitting C-x C-e

```
insert (getenv "HOME")
```

Emacs will display your home path at the bottom (mine defaulted to ...Documents and Settings\UserName)
I haven't worked out a good way to change it, but you're supposed to be able to simply add HOME as an environment variable (that didn't work for me).

It's also talked about a bit more over here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html

Also remember that the file has to be ".emacs" and not myConfig.emacs or something of the like.  Use bash command ren to rename the file (windows explorer won't let you have nameless files)