# Octave mode in Emacs won't automatically load for a .m file

Tags: matlab, emacs, octave

I have the following code in my init.el file:

```
(autoload 'octave-mode "octave-mode" nil t)
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (cons '("\\.m$" . octave-mode) auto-mode-alist))

(add-hook 'octave-mode-hook
       (lambda ()
       (abbrev-mode 1)
       (auto-fill-mode 1)
       (if (eq window-system 'x)
       (font-lock-mode 1))))
```

And I'm using version 24.1.1 of emacs which has built-in support for Octave. However, when I open a file with a .m extension, it seems to go into Obj-C mode. I end up having to open the .m file, and then execute M-x-octave-mode for it to get enabled. Why is this, and how can I fix it so it loads automatically?

Comment: See answer to the question [Emacs change file extension - mode association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941995/emacs-change-file-extension-mode-association)

Comment: For 24.1 you don't need the autoload, since that's already predefined.  You also don't need to explicitly enable font-lock-mode.
As for your problem, I can't reproduce it, so you probably have some other code in your .emacs which interferes.

Comment: @carandraug I did see the response to that question -- that user had a typo in "octave-mode"; I also tried using add-to-list instead of setq/cons but that still didn't help.


I don't know where the octave-mode.el file is.. I don't have a load-path variable set in my init.el, should I be calling that file into load-path? How is octave mode working right now at all if it isn't in my load-path?